# Passing class type to a method

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

In Java, how can you pass the Type of a class as a parameter of a method ?

The example I gave is a basic query using Parse.com Android SDK

Today I need to do this:

```java
//-- This will fetch the car objects
ParseQuery<CarItem> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(CarItem.class);
query.findInBackground( (FindCallback<CarItem>) callback)

//-- This will fetch the trucks objects
ParseQuery<TruckItem> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(TruckItem.class);
query.findInBackground( (FindCallback<TruckItem>) callback)
```

I want to be able to have a method `fetchObjectList()` that takes as a parameter the type of object I want to fetch and calls the correct `callback` function.

```java
public void fetchObjectList( ... classType, ... callback) {

    ParseQuery<classType> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(classType.class);

    query.findInBackground( (FindCallback<classType>) callback);

}
```

At the end I want to be able to do this:

```java
fetchObjectList(CarItem, callback1);
fetchObjectList(TruckItem, callback2);
```

Comment: Talking about Generics?
`public void fetchObjectList(<T> classType)`

Comment: @NicolasSimon Your code is not even syntactically correct; and not answering what he asked for. He wants to pass the type of a class (which resembles to ClassName.class or someObject.getClass(); so an object of type Class<T>).

Comment: Yes you can pass that. 

`public MyClass method1(MyClass obbject) {  }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you're after something like

```
public <T> void fetchObjectList(Class<T> classType, FindCallback<T> callback) {
    ParseQuery<T> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(classType);

    query.findInBackground(callback);
}
```

> In Java, how can you pass the Type of a class as a parameter of a method ?

To pass the type of a class as parameter, you either do

```
fetchObjectList(String.class, someCallback);
```

or, if you don't know the type statically, you could do

```
fetchObjectList(someObj.getClass(), someCallback);
```

Comment: It works! Just need to Extends the ParseObject class like so: `public <T extends ParseObject> void fetchObjectList...`